# How to authenticate submissions to a PHP service

Tags: php, rest

I have a website service (written in `PHP` and accessible only via HTTPS) that allows selected partner companies to submit data from their CMS's, which will then be stored in a `MySQL` database after validation.

But I wish to prevent someone that has discovered the service (e.g. a teenage hacker that wishes to cause trouble by bombarding the URL with multiple requests) from submitting to the service. In other words, how can I authenticate submissions to the service URL?

Sorry if this seems like a layman question, but this is a solo project and I haven't encountered the need to protect a service like this before.

Many thanks.

Comment: since the companies are "selected", assign them each a unique hash upon enrolling into the service? same concept as a password, but a provided one rather then chosen one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Authenticate every request

For example you can use a friendly api-auth system like [JWT](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/)

#### Limit calls to your api

[Throttle your api](https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/05/28/throttle-your-api-calls-ratelimitbundle/)